# Anonymous Function return value

Tags: php, return, anonymous-function

**Update:** Starting with PHP7, it is now possible to use anonymous function dereferencing using the syntax:

```
$array[] = [
    'new' => (function()
    {
        ...
        return mt_rand();
    })(),

    'or' => getClosure()()
]
```

---

Original post: I've recently experimenting with some things, and wondered if there was any way to use the return value of an anonymous function

Lets say I had a for-loop that made an array that each value of the array had to have a database call, something I would like to do is:

```
for($i = 0; $i != 10; $i++)
{
    $array[] = [
        'new' => function(){
            // some proccesing here maybe
            // lets use mt_rand for this example.
            return mt_rand();
        },

        'old' => function(){
            return mt_rand();
        }
    ];
}
```

or maybe

```
echo function(){
     // again, we'll just use mt_rand
     return mt_rand();
};
```

These both return a `closure` class. Is there anyway to actually pass the return value of them back to the array or echo, for the examples above?

Update: I've established this isn't possible so, feature request can be found here: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64608

Comment: Do you really need an anonymous function? Sounds like you need a regular one and just call it inside the loop

Comment: Depends on what php version you have... I believe php 5.4 might be able to do this, but servers running older packages (i.e. Debian Squeeze I know runs php 5.3) won't.

Comment: @JulianH.Lam my examples were tested on PHP 5.4.13

Comment: @JulianH.Lam Anonymous functions are available since PHP 5.3

Comment: I've established this isn't possible so, feature request can be found here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64608

Comment: @JordanDoyle You want to define and immediately execute an anonymous function. While the ticket you found states that this is currently impossible, I wonder if there are many occasions this has to be used. The way you phrased your question suggest that it is impossible - which is not the case. Your loop fills an array with a number of anonymous functions. Why should they be executed at once? Perhaps it might be a very good idea to only execute them when needed.

Comment: @Sven they need to be executed at once to work with a template system.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Simplest workaround to date:

```
echo call_user_func(function () { return 'foo'; });
```

Comment: anonymous function dereferencing is now available in PHP7!

Answer (score 2):

Try assigning the anonymous `function` to a variable.

```
$myFunc = function() {
  return 'Test';
}

echo $myFunc(); // Outputs Test
```

The value of the function itself is not the return value. The return value is the value returned by the function when the function is `called`.

**Edit:**

As suggested by [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze), you can use [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php). Another way to achieve what you want is to make use of php's [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), which is by no means a good coding practice.

```
$array[] = array(
  'new' => call_user_func(function() {
     // some proccesing here maybe
     // lets use mt_rand for this example.
     return mt_rand();
  }),
  'old' => call_user_func(function() {
    return mt_rand();
  }),
);
```

[`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

```
echo eval('$x = function() {
  // some proccesing here maybe
  // lets use mt_rand for this example.
  return mt_rand();
}; return $x();');
```

Comment: I believe OP is looking for the value to be returned when accessing `$myFunc`, not `$myFunc()`.

Comment: @TimCooper No, you need the function calling, see here http://codepad.viper-7.com/3nnjGW

Comment: @Sam: Yes, I am aware you have to evaluate the function to get the return value, but I believe this is a question on where you do the evaluating.  I think OP wants the anonymous function to be evaluated when it's defined.

Comment: `eval` is about the worst solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

The closure appears to have to be assigned before it can be de-referenced - Try this below code:

```
for($i = 0; $i != 10; $i++)
{
    $array[] = [
    'new' => call_user_func(function(){
        // some proccesing here maybe
        // lets use mt_rand for this example.
        return mt_rand();
    }),

    'old' => call_user_func(function(){
        return mt_rand();
    })
    ];
}
```

[edit] - Modified to use call_user_func() instead of custom function - doh!

Answer (score 0):

You must assign the function to a var, [look here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/YoTvhn)

This work

```
    for($i = 0; $i != 10; $i++)
 {
$array[] = [
    'new' => function(){
        // some proccesing here maybe
        // lets use mt_rand for this example.
        return mt_rand();
    },

    'old' => function(){
        return mt_rand();
    }
];
}
echo $array[5]['new']();
```

or

```
$function = function(){
 // again, we'll just use mt_rand
 return mt_rand();
};

echo $function();
```

Comment: In my case I need the return straight off the bat, Running `$a = function(){ return mt_rand(); }();` doesn't work.

Comment: Because that is an assignament, you can do $a(), what's the problem?